# Is 95% confidance interval always included in minimum-maximum interval?

Tags: statistics, maxima-minima, confidence-interval

Is 95% confidance interval always included in minimum-maximum interval ?

I have a set of altitudes (Z). I calculate the mean Z and the 95% confidance interval. Will the bounds of this confidance interval be included in the [Zmin - Zmax] interval, or can they be out of it ?

Comment: It seems you are asking if [confidence intervals are open or closed intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15872/are-confidence-intervals-open-or-closed-intervals).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends slightly on how you calculate your confidence interval for the mean and critically on the sample size.  My simulation suggested usually not for a sample size of $4$ but usually for a sample size of $10$

Comment: @angryavian, no, my question is more : if I have a sample and I calculate the 95% confidance interval, would this interval uper bound always be lower than maximum value of the sample and would the lower bound of the confidance interval be always higher than the minimum value of the sample ?

Comment: @Henry thank you for your answer. If I understand well, the answer would be no ? i.e. confidance interval bounds are not necessary limited to the maximum and minimum values of the sample

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the clarification. The only requirement for a 95% confidence interval is that it contains the true unknown mean with 95% probability (w.r.t. the randomness of your data). 95% confidence intervals are therefore not unique (although we typically work with intervals that are centered at your point estimate, in this case the sample mean). You can define a confidence interval that lies within $[z_{\min}, z_{\max}]$, but in general you can also have confidence intervals that also have points outside of this range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not always.

If you take the usual definition of a $95\%$ confidence interval for the mean as

$$\frac1n \sum x_i \pm t_{n-1:0.975}\,\sqrt{\frac1{n(n-1)}\sum\left(x_i -\frac1n \sum x_j\right)^2}$$

then I think this confidence interval will never enclose $\big(\min(x_i),\max(x_i)\big)$ when $n\in\{2,3,4\}$, while for larger $n$ it can.   An example of the best case is $x_1=-n, x_n=n$ and the other $x_i=0$, in which case $\bar{x}=0$ and the confidence interval for the mean when $n=4$ is about $[-5.2,5.2]$ so not contained in $[-4,4]$; when $n=5$ the confidence interval is  about $[-4.4,4.4]$ and is contained in $[-5,5]$, and similarly for large $n$ with a confidence interval heading towards about $[-2.77,2.77]$ as $n$ increases, well within $[-n,n]$. Note that $2.77 \approx 1.96 \sqrt{2}$.

For $n\ge 7$ drawn from a normally distributed random variable, the range probably will contain the confidence interval for the mean, but it does not have to do so even for extremely large $n$. Consider as an example of a worst case the observations $x_n=n$ and the other $x_i=0$.  Then $\bar{x}=1$ and the confidence interval for the mean heads towards about $[-0.96, 2.96]$ (wider for smaller $n$) and clearly overlaps the minimum observation of $0$.

What is true is that for all $n\gt 1$ the $50\%$ confidence interval for the mean is always contained in the range of observations (for $n=2$ the two intervals coincide), and that for large $n>90$ the $68\%$ confidence interval for the mean is always contained in the range of observations (note $2\Phi(1)-1\approx 0.6827$).

Comment: Thank you for this detailled answer!